# Поиск в массиве php по мак адресу

Tags: php, поиск

php
Есть два массива один c номером порта, маком сетевого устройства

```php
Array
(
[0] = > Array
     (
         [mac_id] => 00:07:e9:32:e5:58
         [port_number] => 15
         [date_updated] => Array
                           (
                           [$date] => 1644511780778
                           )
      )
```

И второй с мак адресами и производителем вида

```php
Array
(
[0] = > Array
     (
         [mac] => 00:00:0C
         [manufacter] => Cisco Systems
      )
[1] = > Array
     (
         [mac] => 00:00:0D
         [manufacter] => Fibronics
      )
```

Подскажите как сделать поиск по имеющимся мак адресам первого [mac_id] массива во втором[mac], и в случае совпадения отображать производителя [manufacter]?

Comment: Циклы уже знаете?

Comment: Пробую foreach ($data as $row) {   foreach ($cursor as $document) { $s=mb_substr($document['mac_id],0,8); if ($row['mac']==$s) { echo $row['manufacter']; }}  зависает

Comment: у вас там миллиард значений?

Comment: одной закрывающей фигурной скобки не хватает кстати

Comment: 44 000 :) , сейчас отобразил совпадения но почему то не все

Comment: 44000 - зачем столько?

Comment: "почему-то не все" --- **[Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482)**

Comment: это бд мак адресов всех производителей поэтому такая большая, задача состоит в том чтобы найти производителя по маку

Comment: Это что за задача? И их надо всееее отобразить? Если нет - то запускать надо в CLI либо вообще через БД. Если отображать  - то надо делать через пагинацию. Иначе если будет 1000000000 значений, то будет конец света

Comment: отобразить нужно те, которые в этом массиве Array ( [0] = > Array ( [mac_id] => 00:07:e9:32:e5:58 [port_number] => 15 [date_updated] => Array ( [$date] => 1644511780778 ) )  значений около 300 , менял местами циклы информация не отображается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
<?php
$devicesList = [ ['mac_id' => '00:07:e9:32:e5:58', 'port_number' => 15, 'date_updated' => [] ] ];
$manufacturersList = [ ['mac' => '00:00:0C', 'manufacter' => 'Cisco Systems'], 
                       ['mac' => '00:00:0D', 'manufacter' => 'Fibronics '], 
                       ['mac' => '00:07:E9', 'manufacter' => 'Intel Corp']
                     ]; 

foreach( $devicesList as $device ) {
    $deviceMacAddr = $device['mac_id'];
    $manufacturerName = "unknown";
    echo "device:\n";
    echo "==========\n";
    echo "mac addr:".$deviceMacAddr."\n";
    echo "manufacturer: ";
    foreach( $manufacturersList as $manufacturer ) {
        $manufacturerMacAddr = mb_convert_case( $manufacturer['mac'], MB_CASE_LOWER);
        if ( mb_substr( $deviceMacAddr, 0, mb_strlen( $manufacturerMacAddr ) ) == $manufacturerMacAddr ) {
            $manufacturerName = $manufacturer['manufacter'];
            break;
        }
    }
    echo $manufacturerName."\n\n";
}
```

Результат

```
device:
==========
mac addr:00:07:e9:32:e5:58
manufacturer: Intel Corp
```

P.S Но проще через CURL сразу лезть например на https://macaddress.io/ и парсить ответ оттуда - и не нужно хранить у себя всю эту базу вендоров оборудования

Comment: Спасибо!Код рабочий